# Maximum Principle for Heat Equation Proof (?)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Is the following a correct proof? It is easier than a proof I have been provided with, but I feel like it is wrong.

Prop: If $ u$ satisfies $ u_{t} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} u_{x_{i} x_{i} }   $ on $\ D \times [0,T] $ where $ D $ is some open domain , then u attains its maximum on $\ \partial D$

Proof: By Heine-Borel, $ u $ attains its maximum on $\partial D \cup D $ .

Suppose $u$ attains its maximum at $ x_0 \in D $. At $x_0$ then $u_t = 0 $ (by Fermat), and $ u_{x_{i} x_{i}} < 0$ (as the Hessian is negative definite).

This contradicts our heat equation and therefore the maximum must be attained in $ \partial D $.

I think the mistake is where I claim $u_{x_{i} x_{i}} < 0$, so maybe I am confused about the Hessian.

Comment: I was using this a bit. Its possible I have misunderstood it. thanks for helping and  I apologize for my awful spelling.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(mathematics)#Several_variables

Comment: What theorem by Fermat are you quoting?

Comment: i might have mixed it up. the theorem i was using was: at a local minima/maxima NOT on the boundary we have first derivative is zero

Comment: So, it's not clear to me what you are trying to prove. I think what you are trying to show is that if you fix a time $t$, then the resulting function of $x$ (on $D$) attains its maximum on the boundary $\partial D$. Is this right?

Comment: Or, are you looking at the maximum as a function of $(t,x)$ on $D\times [0,T]$?

Comment: just slammed my head on the desk - i've made a mistake writing this question out. it should be the max on $\partial D \times [0,T] \cup D \times {0} $

Comment: i think i know my mistake now though. thanks for your help

Comment: Ok. Good luck. $\textbf{}$

Answer (score 2):

Corrections:

1. $u$ attains maximum in $K=(D\cup\partial D)\times [0,T]$, if $D$ is bounded.
2. $u$ does not attain maximum at $x_0$ but at a point of the form $(x_0,t_0)$.
3. It $(x_0,t_0)$ is an interior point, i.e., $(x_0,t_0)\in D\times (0,T)$, then $u_t=0$ and $u_{x_ix_i}\le 0$.

So, you do not have sufficient amount of evidence to show that $u$ can attain maximum on the boundary.

Hint. You need to consider $u_\varepsilon(x,t)=u(x,t)+\varepsilon|x|^2$.

Comment: thanks! I have proven it this way with the epsilon, in my tiredness i thought i had an easier proof but i was being stupid haha.